# Jest coverage, all values at zero

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I introduced code coverage in my project, but all the values (except one) are stuck at zero.

Here is my jest-config.json:

```
{
  "collectCoverageFrom": [
    "../shared/utils/*.js"
  ],
  "coverageDirectory": "<rootDir>/coverage",
  "coverageThreshold": {
    "global": {
      "branches": 0,
      "functions": 0,
      "lines": 0,
      "statements": 0
    }
  },
  "moduleFileExtensions": [
    "js"
  ],
  "moduleNameMapper": {
    "\\.(css|scss)$": "identity-obj-proxy"
  },
  "moduleDirectories": [
    "node_modules",
    "job-board/node_modules"
  ],
  "modulePaths": [
    "<rootDir>/client"
  ],
  "roots": [
    "<rootDir>",
    "<rootDir>/../shared"
  ],
  "testRegex": "\\.test\\.js$"
}
```

My files being tested are in `../shared/src/utils/*.js` and my tests are in `../shared/src/utils/__tests__/*.test.js`.

And when I run `node --harmony_proxies node_modules/jest-cli/bin/jest.js --config ./jest-config.json --coverage`, I get this result:

[image: coverage result]

Only, nearly all the functions in those files are fully tested...

Has anyone come across this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Reproduced the issue on https://github.com/Zephir77167/jest-issues

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem? I'm facing it too myself

Comment: Try `jest  --coverage --watchAll`

Answer (score -3):

Run jest --coverage command to check coverage

Comment: Refer the link, you may get some help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50992518/jest-ignore-file-pattern-for-code-coverage