# How can I ignore a file pattern for Jest code coverage?

Tags: javascript, jestjs

In my Jest tested project I have `*.entity.ts` files. I don't want these files to be included in my coverage test.

According to the documentation at https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/configuration.html#coveragepathignorepatterns-array-string there is a `coveragePathIgnorePatterns` setting which you can use in the `package.json`

I've tried regex and file patterns but none of these just ignores the `*.entity.ts` files in the final report.

When I add for example `"coveragePathIgnorePatterns": ["common"]` my tests won't even run anymore.

Any thoughts on how I can make Jest skip the `*.entity.ts` in the coverage tests?

My Jest section in the package.json looks like:

```
{
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
        "js",
        "json",
        "ts"
    ],
    "rootDir": "src",
    "testRegex": ".spec.ts$",
    "transform": {
        "^.+\\.(t|j)s$": "ts-jest"
    },
    "coverageDirectory": "../coverage"
}
```

Answer (score 152, accepted):

I use an external JSON file to hold my Jest configuration and run it from my `package.json` using npm:  `jest --config jest.config.json --no-cache`

jest.config.json

```
{
    "collectCoverage": true,
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
        "src/**/*.ts"
    ],
    "coveragePathIgnorePatterns": [
        "node_modules",
        "test-config",
        "interfaces",
        "jestGlobalMocks.ts",
        ".module.ts",
        "<rootDir>/src/app/main.ts",
        ".mock.ts"
    ],
    "coverageDirectory": "<rootDir>/coverage/",
    "coverageThreshold": {
        "global": {
            "branches": 20,
            "functions": 30,
            "lines": 50,
            "statements": 50
        }
    },
    "mapCoverage": true,
    "preset": "jest-preset-angular",
    "setupTestFrameworkScriptFile": "<rootDir>/src/setupJest.ts",

    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
        "<rootDir>/node_modules/(?!@ionic-native|@ionic|@ngrx|angular2-ui-switch|angularfire2|jest-cli)"
    ],
    "verbose": false
}
```

My coverage does not include the files listed in the "coveragePathIgnorePatterns".  Maybe the source line "/src/app/main.ts" is the entry you need.

Comment: Simple reminder: path patterns are regular expressions

Comment: `coveragePathIgnorePatterns` was the answer I was looking for. Upvoted.

Answer (score 44):

You can add a ! mark in collectCoverageFrom parameter to exclude it from counting.
Here any file inside a subfolder of src dir

```
  collectCoverage: true,
  collectCoverageFrom: ['src/**/*.ts','!src/*/filesToExclude.ts']
```

Comment: I am confused now. Does a ! ( not) inside collectCoverageFrom mean the same as keeping that file regex inside coveragePathIgnorePatterns ?

Comment: I personally do not think this is as clear as adding "coveragePathIgnorePatterns" and managing a separate array for folders NOT to cover.

Answer (score 7):

Also you can add to your `package.js` the following:

```js
... // Other data
"jest": {
    "coveragePathIgnorePatterns" : [
      "<rootDir>/src/index.js",
      "<rootDir>/src/reportWebVitals.js"
    ]
}
... // Other data
```

That's the only configuration you need to get it working

Comment: starts throwing babel errors when doing this

Answer (score -2):

In my case the following *rootDir* jest parameter meant that the <rootDir> was the 'test' directory.

```
jest --rootDir=./test
```