# Angular jest how to ignore *.spec.ts file in coverage report?

Tags: angular, testing, jestjs, code-coverage

An angular project which use jest to run:

```
jest --coverage
```

then generate a index.html in coverage directory.
How to ignore `*.spec.ts` file in the coverage report?

Answer (score 0):

See my answer on [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50992518/how-can-i-ignore-a-file-pattern-for-jest-code-coverage/50993877#50993877)

The short answer is to add it to the coverageIgnorePatterns option.

I use an external JSON file to hold my Jest configuration and run it from my `package.json` using npm:  `jest --config jest.config.json --no-cache`

jest.config.json

```
{
    "collectCoverage": true,
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
        "src/**/*.ts"
    ],
    "coveragePathIgnorePatterns": [
        "node_modules",
        "test-config",
        "interfaces",
        "jestGlobalMocks.ts",
        ".module.ts",
        "<rootDir>/src/app/main.ts",
        ".mock.ts"
    ],
    "coverageDirectory": "<rootDir>/coverage/",
    "coverageThreshold": {
        "global": {
            "branches": 20,
            "functions": 30,
            "lines": 50,
            "statements": 50
        }
    },
    "mapCoverage": true,
    "preset": "jest-preset-angular",
    "setupTestFrameworkScriptFile": "<rootDir>/src/setupJest.ts",

    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
        "<rootDir>/node_modules/(?!@ionic-native|@ionic|@ngrx|angular2-ui-switch|angularfire2|jest-cli)"
    ],
    "verbose": false
}
```

My coverage does not include the files listed in the "coveragePathIgnorePatterns".  Maybe the source line "/src/app/main.ts" is the entry you need.